# Is there a way to delete a date in a range of dates?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have a range of dates and a date:

- `dates`==> `Wed, 20 Nov 2019...Sat, 30 Nov 2019:Range`
- `date` ==> `Wed, 20 Nov 2019`

**Is there a way to eliminate the `date` from the `dates` range?**

For reference, I imagine something similar to:

```
[1, 2, 7, 4, 5] - [7] which results in => [1, 2, 4, 5]
```

Comment: No. Not without converting the range into an array. This is a textbook X&Y question though - ask about the problem you are trying to solve instead of your idea of the solution.

Comment: Please see "[ask]" and the linked pages and "[mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)".
Did you research this? Where? If it didn't help tell us why. What did you try? If you didn't try, why not? If you did, what did you do? We'd like to see your minimal attempt to solve it.

Comment: _"I imagine something similar to: ..."_ – that should work just fine with date instances instead of integers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ActiveSupport provides the [`Enumerable#without`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Enumerable.html#method-i-without) method. In your case, you can achieve this by:

```
dates.without(date)
```

Comment: Note that the resulting value is no longer a range, but an array.

Comment: I don't know Rails but I'm curious about that method. Being an `Enumerable` method it should work with an object of any class that includes `Enumerable`, such as `Array`, `Range` and `Set`. What about `Hash`? Would it take a key-value pair as argument and return an array of all other key-value pairs in the hash?

Comment: @CarySwoveland For hashes it takes the key to remove and returns a copy of the hash without the given keys. Similar to `slice` but inverted. For arrays, ranges and sets it returns an array since they don't define their own `reject` or return an array from `reject` already. https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/09a2979f75c51afb797dd60261a8930f84144af8/activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext/enumerable.rb#L127-L135